# DEFAULT doesn't work in SET data

Tags: mysql, sql

Help me please

```
CREATE TABLE RET (anim SET('dog','pig','voon') DEFAULT 'pig');
```

Insert :

```
INSERT INTO RET VALUES('root')  //empty string! Why? DEFAULT doesn't work!
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`DEFAULT` doesn't  replace an invalid value, it just defines the default value to use if one is not specified in the insert.

Comment: what if it is specified as NULL in the insert? Does the NULL-value get replaced with the default or not?

Comment: @Jorrit  `null` is a value, so it will be used instead of the default.  Fiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea8037/1

Comment: A empty string "" is a value.

Answer (score 6):

It works as it should.
Change your schema like this for example

```
CREATE TABLE RET (id int, anim SET('dog','pig','voon') DEFAULT 'pig');
```

And then omit `anim` column in your insert

```
INSERT INTO ret (id) VALUES(1);
```

Or use `DEFAULT` keyword

```
INSERT INTO ret (id, anim) VALUES(2, DEFAULT);
```

Output:

```
| ID | ANIM |
-------------
|  1 |  pig |
|  2 |  pig |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b229/1)** demo

Answer (score 3):

+1 to @peterm's answer, but FWIW here are a couple of other ways you can illustrate the behavior:

```
INSERT INTO ret (anim) VALUES (DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO ret () VALUES ();
```

The reason why inserting the value 'root' results in an empty string instead of the default value is that default does not kick in when you specify a value.

The value 'root' isn't one of the valid entries in the definition of the SET, but under default behavior MySQL "truncates" the invalid value(s), and insert an empty set.  It generates a warning when it truncates the invalid value, but it does not block the INSERT from happening.

You can set strict mode to disable the automatic truncation.  This turns warnings into errors, and the INSERT will fail.

```
mysql> SET SQL_MODE=STRICT_ALL_TABLES;
mysql> INSERT INTO RET VALUES('root');
ERROR 1265 (01000): Data truncated for column 'anim' at row 1
```

Comment: good comment :"MySQL "truncates" the invalid value(s), and insert an empty set.".Tanks for your help.